# Example of randomization inference failure?

Tags: self-study, p-value, experiment-design, permutation-test, fishers-exact-test

**Randomization inference failure?**

If we want to test the sharp null hypothesis rather than the weak null hypothesis we can use randomization inference (RI).

**Definition $H_{0,sharp}$: Sharp null hypothesis of no effect**
The treatment effect is zero for all subjects. Formally, $Y_i(1) = Y_i(0)$ for all $i$.

**Definition $H_{0,weak}$: Null hypothesis of no average effect (sometimes called the *weak null hypothesis*)**
The average treatment effect is zero. Formally, $\mu_{Y(1)} = \mu_{Y(0)}$.

Let’s say we have a situation where the treatment effect is positive for half of the units and negative for the other half of the units, and the relative magnitudes of the treatment effects are inversely proportional to each experimental arm’s size. For example, if 50% of units were assigned to treatment, the magnitude of the treatment effects would be the same with opposite signs. 5 for half of observations and -5 for the other half, for instance.

The average treatment effect is equal to zero but the treatment effect for each unit is not zero. Therefore, the null hypothesis of zero average treatment effect is true, but the sharp null hypothesis of no effect for all units is false. But when we run the below test, randomization inference fails to detect an effect.

**If I am not making a mistake in the RI procedure, then why does RI fail to detect that there is a treatment effect for every unit?**

We still succeed in detecting a difference in the variance of the treatment group's outcome, that is, it is larger than what we would expect by chance, but I want to better understand the null result in the test for the treatment effect on the primary outcome $Y$.

```
set.seed(42)
N <- 1000
Z <- rep(0,1000)
treated_share <- 0.5
m <- N*treated_share # size of treatment group
Z[sample(1:1000, size = m)] <- 1

# Simulate data such that the ATE=0
# But the actual treatment effect is positive for 
# half of units and negative for the other half
Y0 <- rep(0, times = N) + rnorm(n=N)
Y1 <- rep(NA, times = N)
Y1[1:m] <- Y0[1:m] + 2/treated_share  # The treatment effect is positive for half of units
Y1[(m+1):1000] <- Y0[(m+1):1000] - 2/(1-treated_share)  # The treatment effect is negative for the other half

# Define the observed Y values
Y <- Z*Y1 + (1-Z)*Y0
mean(Y) # equals 0

# T-test: Test the null hypothesis of ATE=0
t.test(Y[Z==1], Y[Z==0]) # t-test p value = 0.97

# Set randomization inference
nsims <- 10000
ATE_obs <- mean(Y[Z==1]) - mean(Y[Z==0]) # Define the observed test statistic
ATE_sims <- c() # Define holder vector for simulated ATEs

var_obs <- var(Y[Z==1])
var_sims <- c() # Define holder vector for simulated treatment-group variance

# Test the sharp null hypothesis of zero treatment effect for all units
for(i in 1:nsims){
  Z_sim <- sample(Z)
 ATE_sims[i] <- mean(Y[Z_sim==1]) - mean(Y[Z_sim==0])
 var_sims[i] <- var(Y[Z_sim==1])
}


mean( abs(ATE_sims) >= ATE_obs) # RI p value for sharp null hypothesis of no effect for all units

# Visualize the randomization inference results for the treatment effect
hist(ATE_sims, breaks = 40)
abline(v = ATE_obs, col="red", lty = 3)


mean( abs(var_sims) >= var_obs) # RI p value for test of equal variances

# Visualize the randomization inference results for the variance
hist(var_sims, breaks = 40, xlim = c(0,450))
abline(v = var_obs, col="red", lty = 3)
```

Comment: The distribution of the test statistic may be derived using the sharp null hypothesis, but that doesn't imply that the test is equally powerful against all alternatives. The choice of test statistic is crucial to determining against which alternatives your test has power - which your results demonstrate,

Comment: @Scortchi Good point. So is there a disconnect between the test statistic and the test when we use the difference-in-means to test the sharp null -- that is, using a sample-level test statistic for an observation-level test?

Comment: Not at all. The difference in means is particularly sensitive to certain kinds of discrepancy with the null & not to others - that goes for any test statistic you might choose.